# Can I manipulate FDatasnapshot once I have queried for it?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to be able to do some custom filtering on the Datasnapshot I get back. I don't think I can create a complex query to accomplish the result I want.

Is this possible to do and if so, what is the best way of parsing the snapshot?

EDIT:

I am using SwiftyJSON and this is how I ended up parsing it:

```
standbyRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        // do some stuff once

        println(snapshot.value)
        self.parseJson(snapshot.value as NSDictionary)

})

func parseJson(var snapshot:NSDictionary!){

    let json = JSON(snapshot)

    for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
        // key to standby users
        println(key)

        // one object at a time
        println(subJson)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase accepts all the data in `JSON` format only. When you get a `Datasnapshot` of any perticular node of Firebase, you get the complete data below that node, which is in all a JSON only.

Once you get the `Datasnapshot JSON` you can parse it using any `JSON` library, depending on the platform you use.

You can refer here [Datasnapshot Methods](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional library, you can also do something like that:

```
if let email = snapshot.value["email"] as? String {
    user.email = email
}
```

Or if you want to iterate over all values:

```
let enumerator = snapshot.children
while let child = enumerator.nextObject() as? FDataSnapshot {
    println(child.key)
    println(child.value)
}
```