# Cannot get to my "Childrens Children" in Firebase. Access to "nested values."

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Driving me a bit crazy at this point. Trying to access `imageName`, yet always comes up blank. Help most appreciated.

```
 ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value) {
        (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

      for child in result {
        for child2 in child.children {

          // NO ERROR, and NO VALUE RETURNED
          let imageName = (child2 as? NSDictionary)?["imageName"] as? String ?? ""


          // NO VALUE RETURNED - LOOKING TO GRAB imageName HERE
          print("imageName: \(imageName)")

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi frank, thanks for the edits. This is a question that comes up LOTS. Answers are a mishmash of ways to do it. Old FB code, new FB code, etc.

Would be AWESOME if the FB team just did a one pager on "best practices", would help out lots of people moving from Parse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132620/can-i-manipulate-fdatasnapshot-once-i-have-queried-for-it   looks like an interesting parse model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to view each individual child and its values is better to use .childAdded instead.

```
let ref = FirDatabase.database().reference().child("12345")

ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let snap = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }

        let t = test()

        t.profileImageUrl = snap["imageName"] as? String
        t.name = snap["name"] as? String
        t.userID = snapshot.key

        print(snap["imageName"])
```

I used "t" supposing you have some kind of object that represents that node in the databse.

More info in the firebase docs, in retrieve data, child events

> The FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded event is typically used to retrieve a list of items in a Firebase database. The FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/  and this FB page are places to dive into. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132620/can-i-manipulate-fdatasnapshot-once-i-have-queried-for-it

Comment: @EdwardPotter sorry I dont understand what you are trying to say.. Did you try what I told you? Btw that firebase page is from the old documents

Comment: Hi, what I've turned to is implementing swiftyJSON. Will report back.  Like to get this down to to just a line or 2.  Will check out new docs. I'll also try out your implementation today. thanks.

Reference here:  
http://www.waltza.com/2015/12/10/firebase-and-swift-type-safety-with-swiftyjson/

Comment: There is this heated debate, should "t" be an Object or a Struct.  Wow.

Comment: @EdwardPotter well I just used an object to show you a way to store the properties. But here is a link to where they explained when is better to use classes or structs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232799/why-choose-struct-over-class/24232845